# Application of repository pattern in android

Tags: android, repository-pattern

i m working on an android application with repository pattern but i I could not find a complete series of practical implementations of repository pattern in android. 
any recommended tutorial?

Answer (score 3):

I run into the same question and found a good article that compares different approaches for Repository in Android: [Evolution of repository pattern](http://hannesdorfmann.com/android/evolution-of-the-repository-pattern)

It talks about one well-known approach, [Clean architecture](http://fernandocejas.com/2014/09/03/architecting-android-the-clean-way/), suggesting not to overengineer things.

To understand these posts, you should have some experience in using patterns and repository in particular. In my opinion, these posts can lead you to proper implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Implement Repository pattern is pretty easy, you just need to create interface with CRUD methods and use it in your domain logic.

For example:

```
class CreateEntityException;
class ReadEntityException;
class UpdateEntityException;
class DeleteEntityException;

interface Repository<Entity> {
    Entity create(Entity entity) throws CreateEntityException;
    Entity read(long entityId) throws ReadEntityException;
    Entity update(Entity entity) throws UpdateEntityException;
    void delete(long entityId) throws DeleteEntityException;
}
```

Methods count and signature can be different in your own project but an approach is the same.
After it you can create concrete implementation of repository that encapsulate one or another datasource - ContentProviderRepository, OrmLiteRepository, RealmRepository etc. 
Then by using Dependency Injection principle you should inject correct implementation.

There are few good books that covered Repository patterns.
Pattern is independent from platform so it is easy to implement and use every platform.

[https://www.amazon.com/Domain-Driven-Design-Tackling-Complexity-Software/dp/0321125215](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321125215)

https://www.manning.com/books/functional-and-reactive-domain-modeling

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)